# Knockoutjs: ScrollIntoViewTrigger

Tags: knockout.js, triggers, custom-binding

i recently struggled with a problem and although i solved it for me, i'm not sure whether there aren't better solutions out there, so I'd appreciate any comments.

Problem. i wanted to create a 'ScrollIntoView' binding. Since scrolling an element into view, requires the DOM-Element, i wrote a custom binding, which i then wanted to explicitly trigger, whenever i pleased. I started with this code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.scrollTo = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var _value = valueAccessor();
        var _valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(_value);
        if (_valueUnwrapped) {
            element.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
```

};

The binding:

```
<div data-bind="scrollTo: goToThis">
```

And in the ViewModel i had this observable:

```
_self.goToThis = ko.observable(false).extend({notify: 'always'});
```

which I then could just trigger by calling:

```
_self.goTohis(true);
```

So far, so good. However i quickly ran into Problems. Since whenever i set the goTothis() Observable to true, the true value stuck with it, which caused some of the elements to scroll into view, without the user explicity triggering it. For instance, when i changed the view, essentially hiding all the elements with an if binding, and then switched back, the if binding would re-trigger all the goToThis observables, which had previously been set to true. Ugh!

So i thought up this pattern and extended my custum binding like this:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.scrollTo = {
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
            var _value = valueAccessor();
            var _valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(_value);
            if (_valueUnwrapped) {
                element.scrollIntoView();
// resets the trigger value to false. Otherwise there will be more and more ViewModels, where the value is true.
                if (ko.isWriteableObservable(_value) && typeof (_valueUnwrapped) === 'boolean') {
                    _value(false);
                }
            }
        }
   };
```

Essentially resetting the boolean value each time it is triggered.

So i guess my question is this: Has anybody ever written a scrollIntoView binding? If yes, how did you solve it?

And generally, is there a pattern for writing triggers? ie i just want to trigger a binding, but there is no real value change.

best regards
j

Comment: Nice binding! I guess I'd ask what scrolling in the UI means to the view model. Are we bringing something in to focus or scrolling to an arbitrary point? Scrolling to a specific pixel location, for example, would be kinda defeating the point of the MVVM abstractions! What you've implemented certainly fits that particular issue.

The closest existing binding example is focus - it focusses when true and writes false back when focus is lost. I think this very much fits the same pattern.

Comment: Often I find bindings are the correct way to go and the trick is to widen the scope of the binding to encapsulate an issue as a whole and see if the old solution still fits.

If I was breaking this out in to a full solution I'd look at something like the bootstrap navigation spy and provide some kind of two way binding that, for a specific element, sets the bound property to true when the item is scrolled to and false when it is not. We can add functionality for triggering the scroll to on a specific element, which would in turn set all of the other "ScrolledTo" bindings back to false.

Answer (score 7):

Your `scrollTo` handler is fine like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.scrollTo = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var _value = valueAccessor();
        var _valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(_value);
        if (_valueUnwrapped) {
            element.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
};
```

But instead of working with a `goToThis` observable per view model, better would be to have 1 observable in your root which keeps track of the current scroll item and then pass an expression in your binding like this:

```
<div data-bind="scrollTo: $root.scrolledItem() == $data">
```

This way you don't need to reset anything and you don't need an `goToThis` observable per view model.

See http://jsfiddle.net/290ew0nr/1/

Comment: This is excellent.  Can it be applied to a specific `option` of a `select`?

Answer (score 1):

I use `scrollintoview` in my knockout app, but never thought to put it into a `bindingHandler`, probably because I don't feel `scrollintoview` is a relationship between the model and the view.

`scrollintoview` to me is more like a follow up action after we present data on view.

My approach is to use a css binding to mark the item I want to `scrollintoview`, for instance, I mark the element with css class `current-item`, and of course there should be only one item marked with this class in the end.

Then what I need to do is to scroll it into view after ko rebuild all the DOM.
To allow ko to build the view before I ran `scrollintoview`, I need to delay the action.

```
// do my model logic above
// then fire my after-render callback
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.current-item').scrollintoview({direction: 'y'});
  // I am using a different scrollintoview library: https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview
}, 0);
```

BTW, ko provided a better way to do afterRender callback http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_4_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove

You could use a `template`, and put `scrollintoview` in that `template`'s `afterRender` callback.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to tackle this problem is with custom events. You could fire an event from your ViewModel when you need to do the scrolling (supplying any relevant data), and then you define a handler on the page to react to that event. That way you can do all the DOM manipulation in the event handler and keep your ViewModel HTML-agnostic.